# Is Stack Overflow not a forum?

Tags: discussion

Today someone asked in a comment on an off-topic question which is now on hold:

> Is Stack Over Flow not a forum?

See the comment on the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340593/android-devices-for-development?noredirect=1).

So, someone please explain, "what is Stack Overflow?"

Comment: The canonical is *[Are Stack Exchange sites forums?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92115#92115)*. There is also *[Would you recommend Stack Exchange sites vs. other types of fora?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/36828)* (sort of canonical wrt. to *open-forum discussion* vs. ***deliberative assembly***)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Read the [help→tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.

The only point it mentions **forum** is here:

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

Comment: @daCoda Stackoverflow is not intended to teach you basic concepts. That's what books, Google and tutorials are for. Asking on SO is not something that should be done lightly.

Comment: The funny thing is that discussion is still a wickedly important tool to ensure that both questions and answers are correct and complete.

Comment: @dandan78 In that case, I guess the question is as important as the answers in SO.

Comment: @Gimby Which is why comments exist, but as second-class entities.