# Down-vote or give advice in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, downvotes

The newcomers of this forum certainly do not want to be discouraged by downvotes cast against the early questions/answers in their childhood period. Even with the very elegant, well designed, helpful and descriptive [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) provided by the forum guys, silly mistakes are most likely to be made by the absolute beginners like me.

When I first came across this useful site, I was thrilled about it; but now I'm discouraged by continuous downvotes.

I would like the downvoters rather leaving **useful** comments that I personally think might be even more effective than the downvoting strategy.

Useful comments would likely to serve two purposes at a time

1. discouraging the OP from posting similar silly posts
2. encouraging to develop the future posts.

What do you guys think about it? The effect of downvoting has been so much on me that, I am even afraid of this post being downvoted resulting in my reputation score going down to the minimum possible value :(.

Comment: This isn't a useful comment. (or @Will style afgjfghjjfvdafhxdfyxgfcgjkvhkjxdaghcghch Tony the Pony)

Comment: And downvotes don't affect rep on Meta.

Comment: You can only make useful comments when you fully understand the problem.

Comment: If you're having trouble with your questions being downvoted, have you checked out the [ask] page yet? It has advice on writing good questions, and links to extra material you can read. Try reading that and looking back at your downvoted questions to see if you can figure out what's wrong. Since comments on downvotes aren't mandatory, nor should they be (and that has been discussed to death, just search meta for it), the best you can hope for is someone being kind enough to comment, and being able to figure the problem with your question out yourself otherwise.

Comment: What exactly do you want to discuss?  At this point, this reads like you are ranting against people downvoting questions just because they were asked by a new users.  That particular discussion has been discussed to death.  If you have a specific question you would like someone to help you understand why it was downvoted and how to improve it, the Meta community can certainly help.

Comment: @ashubuntu _"You can only make useful comments ..."_ You may receive upvotes with well asked questions. Do you want to have mandatory comments why your questions are upvoted as well (I
'm eager to see these lots and lots, we have so many unconscious upvote mokeys and sockpuppets here)?

Comment: `Useful comments would ... discourag[e] the OP from posting similar silly posts`  all eveidence to the contrary. Sorry this is suggested several times a week.

Comment: ashubuntu I think you missed @πάνταῥεῖ 's point.... (and mine, was my comment really useful?)

Comment: @ashubuntu The wonderful [SO IKEA shop](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for how to build good questions.

Comment: I was just telling myself that we haven't seen this in a couple of days.... of course.  Anyway, with the AMOUNT of crap on this site and the limited number of users who try to keep quality up, new users can't be cuddled too much. It's a shame sometimes but it's the reality of what stack has to deal with. ...

Comment: Pro tip: Make your posts better readable. We have paragraphs besides emphasis as well available with the markdown language used by the SE engine.

Comment: Your assumption this is a [forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/158100) might cause also some of the confusion...

Comment: I would, however, prefer advice like those in the previous comments, to downvoting :). Thank you all for these **USEFUL** comments. Also I want some more downvotes against this question too. Please help me out in this regard. while(true) :).

Comment: It's easy to take voting personally; ideally it would not be.  With bad blood so fast and frequent, it suggests *something* could be improved.  I'd like to see better methods of enculturation--while SO has no problem being whimsical on April Fools day or making hats in winter...it doesn't feel very whimsical when new users are thrown in the "deep end of the pool".  But even minor things aren't tried, like my [pre-flight checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265671/).  For the moment, quality control is seen as higher priority than kindness...hopefully they'll be equal someday. :-/

Comment: @HostileFork In which way is downvoting meant to be _unkind_ per se?? (asking s.o. with _"dat user name"_, and meeting in close votes so often :-P)

Comment: Judging from the comments, I will guess that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604891/j) is what prompted this meta post?  The simplest answer I can give you is your question was closed and downvoted because your question was effectively asking for ***"complete reference of the Java language constructs that are by one way or another related to image handling"***.  While you say "For the beginners, this type of questions is common", these types of questions are not appropriate for Stack Overflow.  We are looking for specific questions and not just a "where can I get this" requests.

Comment: Downvoted because of a yellow submarine stealing my keys

Comment: There is a problem with bad questions and so, yet again, someone wants to move the onus to solve it from the questions posters to the SO answer contributors.  We don't have time to provide comments because we're too busy answering the X good questions and down/close voting the 100X bad questions.

Comment: Also, 'This user has not answered any questions'.

Answer (score 7):

> What do you guys think about it?

That it isn't useful in the end, to require comments on up- or down-votes. These have been designed like this very concsiously. All of the necessary information and signal to anyone given with an up- or downvote is pretty clear and shown when hovering the corresponding buttons with your mouse pointer

- At the down button:

  > This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful
- At the up button:

  > This question shows research effort, it is useful and clear

---

> *"... of this forum ..."*

First you should notice that SO [***isn't a forum***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294774/is-stack-overflow-not-a-forum) but a question and answer site.

> silly mistakes are most likely to be made by the absolute beginners like me.

Yes, that's probable.

> When I first came across this useful site, I was thrilled about it; but now I'm discouraged by continuous downvotes.

If you see a downvote it's a sign that **you need to clarify or improve your question**. These are actually meant to **encourage** you to do so (check the tooltip appearing when hovering your mouse pointer over the downvote button), and not the opposite (discouraging you to ask).

An additional comment would just generate unnecessary noise.

> Useful comments would likely to serve two purposes at a time - discouraging the OP from posting similar silly posts and encouraging to develop the future posts.

There's no need to force downvoters to leave *useful comments*, as mentioned above the downvote itself already contains enough information signal, that something's wrong with the questions (well, there may be unjustified downvotes, but these will not hold over time, when there's no real problem with the question).

---

To improve downvoted questions, you can always double check the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in particular.

---

> I am even afraid of this post being downvoted resulting in my reputation score going down to the minimum possible value :(.

It's pretty much downvoted currently, and as you can see there's no effect on your main user account's reputation.

[Downvotes on meta are different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus?s=1|0.1675).

Comment: I would downvote against your answer if I could because your answer doesn't seem to suit my question. How do you feel about that, boss, even with 28.1k score?

Comment: @ashubuntu _"I would downvote against your answer if I could"_ Can't you do so here?? Well s.o. else seemed to follow your opinion. I think my answer is well formatted to give answers about your doubts and questions. If you don't believe so, improve your question and clarify please.

Comment: Please don't be over-confident about the posts you make. You as well as others have definitely missed the moral viewpoint of my question. You all just want to answer very rigidly (this is very typical of the programmers, according to me) and downvote if questions/answers don't match your quality, I mean your expertise. But questions should be answered so that the query maker can understand with the ability he has got so far.

Comment: @ashubuntu if multiple people (or everyone) misses the 'moral viewpoint' of your question, that's probably a sign that your question isn't particularly clear.

Comment: @ashubuntu There's no ***moral viewpoint*** to be regarded (well there are moral policies we have, but not regarding your particular doubts about what downvoting is meant to), or need to cuddle _newbies_ and wrap them with cotton on this site. We've been doing all our best to make it clear in the Help Center, and the SE policies.

Comment: @ashubuntu just the way you say it ("how do you feel about that, boss") shows your general attitude around downvotes and this community. Honestly, take a breather, realize the rules of this community exist to help the site prosper, and try to work with the rules instead of bucking up and stomping your feet...

Comment: I upvoted this answer as being clear and very much in line to what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

> Down-vote or give advice in comments?

I very often do both. But if I only have time for one, it'll be the first.

Down votes are not meant just to be feedback to the person who asked the question. They are meant as feedback to *other users* to signal that it is a bad question.

There is no shortage of people willing to ask bad questions. People have a finite amount of time to invest in this site, limited by their life span, and though many of us do *try* to encourage people to improve their questions

The sad fact is that a lot of users just dump their questions here and bugger off.

Every user, before asking their questions, is encouraged to read the "About" and "How to Ask" pages. Yet... clearly a lot of them don't. When a user with 1 reputation posts who doesn't have the "Informed" badge we can be almost sure that person hasn't spent just a few minutes to look and see what this site is about.

If your question is being down-voted, be sure you understand the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and have read and absorbed the [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) pages. Provide a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Put some effort into the formatting.

If you're afraid of receiving down-votes for bad questions, then **good**. Anything that motivates people to not ask bad questions is the system at least partially working. If you're **continuously** receiving down votes on your questions then take a step back and try to see why -- rather than blaming the system.

Comment: It's all about _uncommented down-votes_ here ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Indeed. My meta rep ego will never recover from this injustice.

Comment: @tzhx Don't be upset. I accept your answer, and upvote because you have been more logical and softer in answering the question. Congrats from a newbie...

Comment: @ashubuntu I have been well friendly and professional in what I'm saying, can't see about how getting _"softer"_ for your taste. You're just judging by rep of the poster I believe ;-) ... Well, you hate _bosses_, I do so to. I'm not your _boss_ because having ~760 times more rep than you have.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I assure you it wasn't my intent to be "soft". I don't see any substantial difference between my answer and yours -- you just type faster. :)

Comment: @TZHX I love to see the _free flooding_ down-, up-votes and accepts on meta, beyond any _moral_ :-D. It just shows so beautifully how the system really works ;-) ...

Comment: @ashubuntu And now you unaccepted this answer?? Because it got downvotes? Did it serve you well or not? You're just a coward, sorry (and being so about void virtual internet reputation points). How awkward is this please?

Comment: @TZHX Of course [that downvote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295889/down-vote-or-give-advice-in-comments#comment201769_295893) was unjustified, but tactical. I think you received that well.