# Notify users that some other Stack Exchange sites exist based on tags used on question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have a question on topics and specific boards.

I just run into a question on Stack Overflow, *[Why after the spaceships collide with the box collider they are not turning back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912393/why-after-the-spaceships-collide-with-the-box-collider-they-are-not-turning-back)*.

This question is hardly linked to a game (Unity3D). Unity is an engine game, and the Stack Overflow expose a Unity3D tag, but I think this tag should only exist on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

My question is: Do you think that removing tags related to game engine from Stack Overflow will force people to move the right site?

Another question: If removing is a hard way to push people to the right direction, is there a way to pop a message up to the user screen when he tries to use a tag hardly linked to a particular board?

This not only unity3D, it should be Ogre, Xna, etc...

Removing tags is not the right way to do it. Instead, is there a way to notify the user that other boards exists related to the tags used?
XNA, Ogre, Unity, etc... should notice the user that [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour) should be the right place to ask the question.

Comment: Is there a way to force people to comment when they down vote a question :) this would help me to improve my question.

Comment: Voting is different on meta than on normal StackOverFlow. On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.

Comment: Thx @Turamarth, As I said, this is my first question on this board :)

Comment: @pix _"Is there a way to force people to comment when they down vote a question"_ That's another oftenly recurring question: See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295889/down-vote-or-give-advice-in-comments) for example.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is why i just comment on my post and I did not create a new question ;)

Comment: It's a specific programming question, thus it's on topic on Stack Overflow and shouldn't be moved anywhere. The fact that it might also be on topic elsewhere is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok maybe this link is not the best example, but I think there is so many dedicated board (this is gread) that sometime users does not take time to look for the right one before asking a question.
My question would have been better if I directly asked for a way to informe the user that some other board should be the right place for the question. This information should be raised by the tagged used.

Xna, Ogre, Unity should notice the user that, SOGame also exist :)
Same for other particular libs/Framework link to a specific domain.

Comment: StackOverflow exposes a Unity3D tag among others because game development questions are not necessarily off-topic on Stack Overflow. The question you linked looks like SO material to me. So no, don't agree with any of what you say and claim and thus I downvote your feature request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We already have a mechanism for telling the user their question should be on a different SE site **when it doesn't belong here**.

[image: Screenshot of the flag dialog after choosing the "Off topic because..." option. Red circles are drawn around the options for telling the user their question may be on topic at other sites or should be migrated.]

But there is no reason for the system to tell users their **on topic** question is also on topic elsewhere.

1. It implies they shouldn't ask it here, which is wrong.
2. It implies they should ask it at *both* sites, which is also wrong.
3. If all SE sites do this then it creates an infinite loop where Stack Overflow suggests a more specialized site and the other site suggests Stack Overflow.
4. It would be a nightmare to try to keep up with which tags should suggest which other SE sites.
5. It would not improve the experience for the user trying to ask the question in any way.
6. If it really would benefit the user to ask at a different SE instead of Stack Overflow, then someone familiar with that site will say so in the comments. That suggestion, if it occurs at all, should really come from someone familiar with both sites.

Comment: thx for the detailed answer :)