# Is this a bad question or SO users did not read the question clearly?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293929/how-php-gives-error-even-after-exit) today.

It has 3 down votes. And high reputation user(29k) asked "Please show your codes , at least the line 22" as a comment.

As I understand he has not read my question clearly. Because the answer should not depend on the code which is in line 22.

Most are down voted my question like him, not reading my question clearly.

Or actually, is my question a bad question for SO?

Comment: This is issue with every new user entered in stackoverflow. Everyone has right to know why this is happened to them. Regarding question guideline, they are not too good as for new users perspective. As they are just learning to raise question in stackoverflow. This user has 72 score so may be it is right to downvote this user. but certainly not for new user to stackoverflow. may be some edits and comments to them to make question stackoverflow ready from us will help?

Comment: @paul i am saying for questions raised by new users on stack itself  :)

Comment: Let me assure you that the vast majority of users on Stack Overflow can read questions and comprehend them after which a vast minority use their down votes. Receiving down votes is a signal to revisit your post, not to start blaming the voters.

Comment: @rene When I blaming the voters in this question? I am bad at English because it is not my first language. But I asked this question the most polite way I KNOW. I clearly mentioned at ending, "Or actually, is my question a bad question for SO?"

Comment: You are saying: *he has not read my question clearly*. I'm pretty sure everyone did. I'm not saying you're not polite. I try to explain that focusing on what users did wrong is the wrong approach. Set your mind to *What can I do to fix my question so I can address both comments and down votes effectively*

Comment: Downvote should be allowed after certain time limit of question post OR Downvote should decrease 10 score from voter. Then i think people should use it more sensibly.

Comment: @rene I am not saying that everyone did not ready my question. But, Now(after getting answer for my question in SO) I am pretty sure at least 29K rep user didn't read my question. Because he asked in comment  "Please show your codes , at least the line 22" . He has 369 questions on PHP tag and he has defiantly good knowledge about PHP. I am sure that if he read the the my question he understand that line 22 code is not needed to answer my question. Even you can understand it answer of my question https://stackoverflow.com/a/45294026/8246224.

Comment: @jit so your assertion is that reducing feedback will improve question quality. That's not tenable and also tangential to this question.

Comment: @robert nop. just saying to not make uneasy for new users. you can comment first before downvote and after certain time interval downvote also. Also do not take it as personal comment. :)

Comment: @jit There are hordes and hordes of new garbage questions on Stack Overflow each day. No-one has time to help a user who hasn't bothered to read the helpful articles on how to ask good questions, which is why downvotes and closevotes exist. If you put a larger penalty on using the only tools we have for quality control, we won't have quality. We'll just have garbage. But this has been discussed to death in many, many questions on meta over the years.

Comment: Stackoveflow started "For the people From the people". We are here to give and take help. not for quality management. i think stackoverflow creators may agreed on this with me.

Comment: @jit I am really like if this "you can comment first before down vote " feature available on stackoverflow.

Comment: *For the people From the people*? I must have missed that memo.

Comment: @DamithRuwan you can vote on [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351491/making-obligation-adding-comment-for-first-down-vote) of the [many](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295889/down-vote-or-give-advice-in-comments) feature request [already present](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question): You can also lurk a bit on Meta for a couple of days as new posts requesting for comments on downvotes come in on a regular basis.

Comment: @rene Stackoveflow started "For the people From the people".   i think stackoverflow creators may agreed on this with me. >> This is for stackoverflow creators. not for others :)

Comment: @jit I'm pretty sure Joel and Jeff wouldn't have had that slogan on the shortlist, ever.

Comment: @jit You should actually read up a bit on why Jeff and Joel created SO if you want to comment on why they created SO.  They created it because other similar sites were full of crap, and it made finding useful information all but impossible, so they created a site specifically designed with quality control mechanisms to dramatically increase the quality of the contributions.  Downvotes are a very big part of that.  So what you're *actually* proposing is removing one of the key features of why the site was created, and are *contradicting* the founding values of the site.

Comment: @servy i never said to remove it but for the new users who are just trying to enter in stack world should be eased rather than downvoting straightforward without realizing that user what is going on.If you observe some people using it in negative way. good example is i got 2-3 downvotes on my questions after i commented here.(though i dont care). This is just hatred or negative impact of the downvote mechanism."With great power comes great responsibility".This is community site and if it wanna to contribute to community it should follow that understading. if not "lots of websites came & gone".

Comment: @jit you point is correct. Thanks for everyone. After posting this question I got additional 16 down votes and now  I can't even ask question on Stackoverflow. I was blocked for few days.

Comment: @Damith Sorry mate. i just jumped into this accidentally and question getting more attention than usual.

Comment: @jit So you want to greatly limit the ability of that critical feature in the situation where it's most important.  My point remains.  If new users don't want to get downvotes, they should contribute *quality* content, rather than low quality content.  They have more than enough tools at their disposal to do so, if they want to.  Not informing them when they do something wrong doesn't help them at all, it hurts them (because they don't realize that they've made a mistake) and it hurts everyone else, as there's more bad questions on the site.

Comment: @PaulCrovella You said "Users are not voted on, content is; and there is no "right" to know anything.". But actually users are voted on and down. I said it because after I write this question it takes additional  17 down votes. It just because I asked this question. You may not said what I said is correct. But your heart know what is the true.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As the answer notes, the assumption in your question - that line 22 is irrelevant because of line 18 - is incorrect: line 22 is still *parsed* before any of the code is executed, thus the exit in line 18 does not prevent an error in line 22 from causing problems.

You might have guessed that your assumptions were dubious by observing that PHP did, in fact, generate an error for line 22.

In any case, if someone - particularly someone with over 300 posts in the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag - takes the time to point out an omission in your question, it's probably a good idea to humor them; there's at least a slim chance they might actually know what they're talking about.

As for whether your question is "good" or "bad"... The guidance for downvoting doesn't recommend abstract value judgements such as this; instead it recommends downvoting when a question "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". To avoid writing a question that falls into these categories, spend some time searching Stack Overflow for aspects of your question before posting it, and be specific in your question as to what you found and how it failed to help you. You might have noticed that [we have an extensive guide to parse errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them) - if it didn't address your concern, then noting that in your question would go a long way toward helping readers understand where your confusion lies.