# TicketMaster support sending customers to a "forum" - here

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

A new user just posted news of a TicketMaster feature release as [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634746/new-api-filters-with-get-event-good-news). This clearly isn't a question and isn't a good fit for SO. As such, I tried to point out that SO isn't a traditional discussion forum and only Q&A pairs were on-topic. The user's answer was intriguing:

> If you go to developer.ticketmaster.com and 'hover; over Support at the top of the page... it points to here... There is no other "Support". And I think this, while not a question, is under the guidelines of this "specific" forum.

I promptly paid [TicketMaster's support page](http://developer.ticketmaster.com/support/) a visit and the user is correct. Under the heading "Forums" there are 5 links: General Discussion, API Forums, SDK Forums, Widget Forums, and Affiliate Topics. All 5 point to specific tags here on SO (as a matter of fact, all point to the same tag, [ticketmaster-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ticketmaster-api)).

Now I know [we're technically allowing companies to put questions here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product) ([or are we?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow/253584)) but this seems a little ridiculous. SO [isn't a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294774/is-stack-overflow-not-a-forum). It isn't for "general discussion". It likely, without knowing anything about TicketMaster's API, isn't for "affiliate topics". And clearly users are being confused or this one wouldn't be posting a non-question here.

Would it be possible for someone higher in the SO chain of command to either tell TicketMaster that this is not okay, or clarify that I'm misunderstanding?

*Please try to keep the Meta effect to a minimum on the question I linked. The point of this Meta question isn't to complain about this user or his off-topic question. He was obviously just following TicketMaster's instructions and I'd rather not see the downvote flood that so often follows a Meta post.*

Comment: I'm curious how they managed to interpret any of the rules and how-to pages on Stack Overflow to state that not-questions are okay... =D

Comment: I don't know if they intended to self-answer all along, but with much effort on their part, they could turn their question and ["answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634746/new-api-filters-with-get-event-any-new-filters#comment62752672_37634746) into an on-topic Q/A.

Comment: @PetahChristian The question [originally started](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37634746/1) as a forum-type post. I think the edit, and subsequent comment (the question had been closed by that point so no answers were possible), were an attempt to make their content fit within SO's rules.

Comment: SE doesn't mind cornering the market for volunteer-provided support.  Companies like Ticketmaster (egad) don't mind that either.  Everybody loves free beer, if you don't like to brew it then there are always some odds that somebody else does.  If it feels like big companies backed by multi-millionaire investors are taking advantage of you that, yes, they do.  Because they can.  And it is the only real way to ever become a millionaire, they've had practice.

Comment: Can we interest you in the [documentation expansion project](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) instead?  These companies also don't like to spend the money on decent docs for their customers.  2698 free beer votes for that one, you can help!

Comment: I've had a quick look at the other questions in the tag.  Everyone that seems to claim to be working for Ticketmaster apart from *one* person has a total reputation score below 1K.  Even 1K isn't quite enough to do much of anything in terms of moderation, so the concern is very valid.

Comment: I'll reach out to them on Monday. <sigh>

Comment: Ticketmaster is doing something unscrupulous? Stop the presses!

Comment: Where is the WT* button? That unscrupulous ... It would have been  laughable if it was a joke ... but no ... : ı WT* ...

Comment: It's nowhere near as bad, but I recently noticed that Okta is doing something similar (http://developer.okta.com/discussion/). I'd guess many others are too, but the traffic is so low-level that nobody notices / cares. Maybe there should be some more prominent how-to-use-SO-as-your-support-site pages? I think a meta answer (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253852/1180785) is the current source-of-truth, but the help centre (http://stackoverflow.com/help) has nothing obvious, despite being where integrators are likely to look.

Comment: @Dave, if Okta didn't use the word "forum" it'd be perfectly fine.  (and the word "forum" is literally/etymologically fine, but is such a loaded word that we hate it).

Comment: @KirkWoll The problem with that word is that traditionally a forum is for discussion; Stack Exchange websites however are *not* for discussion and that's why describing Stack Exchange websites as 'forums' is incorrect.

Comment: @cybermonkey, oh, I totally agree, and Okta ought to replace that word.  But I think they are using SO in the proper manner otherwise.

Comment: There are a few questions in the Okta tags that clearly indicate that the users think they are talking directly to their support. Not really SO-like.

Comment: Everyone of those forum links point to the same tag on SO, lazy &@£!

Comment: Nice to see the tag editors out in full force, I was just on my way there.

Comment: _No matter what question you have or help you need, **we’re** here for you._ Brilliant

Comment: Excellent answer here - [Square is using SO as their “tech support forum” - lots of off-topic questions as a result](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292340/692942) - especially like *"Make sure we're not your only support option"*, guess TicketMaster didn't read that.

Comment: @Dave There is a help article on that topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: @Tas Playing devils advocate somewhat, if you look at many of the answers in that tag, the users are Ticketmaster employees. Of course, that doesn't excuse what they are doing!

Comment: @J.Steen "They" being Ticketmaster or the users directed here by Ticketmaster? I'm guessing the users didn't read the rules & how-to pages (since they're pretty standard across most *forums*, and if you're directed here by a link saying SO is a *forum*, then of course you're going to expect a *forum* when you get here), and Ticketmaster just doesn't care (because it's...y'know...Ticketmaster).

Comment: Could a banner dynamically added atop pages for currently-abused tags help cut down on the low/no-quality "questions"?  It could also shame the offending company into changing their practices.  "Hey, we just forwarded everyone to a page that says we're inept!"  Companies might be more sensitive to that than to the odd complaint from an unsuspecting user who finds out that the company shunted them to an effective support dead-end.

Comment: I think step 1 would be to charge Ticketmaster a $12.95 Convenience Fee per on-topic question that gets posted here. For off-topic, we can up that to $29.95.

Comment: As I commented on a similar meta question - I'm of the growing mind that SO should be disallowing such behavior in the first place. There have to be at least a dozen Meta threads scattered around, each revolving around a specific company which failed to properly keep its questions within SO's rules. In each case, the users are getting caught in the middle. I would argue we're not here to be ACME Corp.'s free support desk, and that if companies would like their questions outsourced they should be forming a contract with SO. Then SO gets paid, rules get followed, and everybody's happy.

Comment: @jinglesthula Really like that idea but doubt they will want to do that.

Comment: @TimPost FYI: One of the tickmaster-api questions was answered by http://stackoverflow.com/users/6296706/sylvain-gilbert -- his profile says he is a Development Manager at Ticketmaster.

Comment: @jinglesthula - What if the 3rd line of their tag wiki was first: *"Non-technical or general questions should be directed to TicketMaster support..."*? Just immediately shunt them back over to ticket master if their question isn't an API question.

Comment: @rrauenza I've already gone through most of the profiles they all claim to be part of the TicketMaster Develepment Team in various different forms.

Comment: @BSMP that's assuming they even read or notice the tag wiki.

Comment: @Lankymart - The Ticketmaster site links to "questions/tagged/ticketmaster-api" which shows the excerpt for the tag at the top of the question list.

Comment: You may have a point but look I've bought these 2 tickets to Hootie and the Blowfish and I just want to know if you StackOverflow guys can refund the money to my PayPal account because I can't make it...

Comment: As a consumer, I get annoyed when I see several links with different titles/descriptions that all point to the same URL, because that means it's just a generic landing page and I'll have to do some extra hunting to get to the specific page I briefly thought I had found.

Comment: Since Ticketmasters site is almost constantly broken anyway (attempts to buy tickets on their desktop website gives 403s *every, single, time*, it's pretty clear their own development team aren't up to the job. I really like @jinglesthula banner suggestion. Check the referrer and shame them with a big banner "reminding" visitors from there of the rules.

Comment: Looks like the offending links have been removed now. Now they just have no support at all.

Comment: Oh snap, they done did freak out and delete all dem links. Well shoot son! @TimPost great job man, you scared them right good you did.

Comment: @Lankymart what if they use the referrer to only display it to users who actually came there from the offending website, but all other visitors to those tag's pages won't see the banner?

Comment: @Hack-R the proper place for that request is on regular SO.  Meta is only for refunds of tickets purchased with digital currencies.  Did this resolve your question?

Comment: @jinglesthula Yes it did, thank you! I'll give you a good review on the customer support feedback survey.

Comment: @jinglesthula - (in response to banner idea) I think Ticketmaster has probably been properly burned at this point. [Their tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ticketmaster-api) has been just about obliterated (whether or not it was appropriate for vigilante voters to do that is another conversation). I'm willing to bet that there are some high-level emergency conversations going on right now about setting up a proper (and company-controlled) support channel.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I don't think this is anything we haven't seen or handled before. Close questions that are off-topic and direct the asker to the [regular meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) addressing this company cost-cutting measure.

If you happen to see an employee of the company on Stack Overflow responding to Ticketmaster questions, and he/she seems to be unfamiliar with how Stack Overflow works, you may want to comment and direct them to the official help page for product owners: [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

The glorious [Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) has stated that he'd reach out to them tomorrow (thanks Tim!), but I'd say this is just business as usual -- close/downvote as needed.

For what it's worth:

1. You really weren't kidding -- they're even offloading their "general discussion" to Stack Overflow tagged questions:

   [image: Ticketmaster linking to SO as support "forums"]
2. I don't think you're misunderstanding.

As they're sending a very wide array of questions our way (general discussion to affiliate 'topics'), (and as they didn't bother even adding a description to the tag,) the [ticketmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ticketmaster) tag has been edited to at least give their users a warning.

The tag edit was done on [ticketmaster-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ticketmaster-api). If someone with the permissions would be so nice to synonym it to tag [ticketmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ticketmaster), I'd be thankful.

Comment: Quick curiosity - `== $0`?

Comment: @Kyll [The Last Selected DOM Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999739/what-is-0-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: @Kyll flagging as *not meta enough*. Take your silly programming questions to the main site.

Comment: Flagging a meta question on meta as not meta? That's pretty meta.  As is pointing it out.  As was that.  Send help

Comment: What annoys me most about this is the *we're here for you*. Help is not *here* (the support page) AND it's not the *we* (the TicketMaster people) who would be offering the help. UGH. This is not a forum hosting site...

Comment: @Laurel If I was still capable of feeling things, I'd probably agree.  The productive thing to do is to communicate clearly to askers that we're interested in *on-topic* programming problems -- and that all Ticketmaster or support-experience complaints should be directed at Ticketmaster's channels.  No need to get emotionally involved or go out of our way to accommodate the unpaid-outsourcing approach.

Comment: I've declared war on [tag:Ticketmaster-api]

Comment: @Lankymart "*we're here for you*" ;) But no, really, wars are baaad.

Comment: @Lankymart When you say "declared war" - could you elaborate - I'm slightly concerned about what you might be planning to do...

Comment: @JonClements just highlighting that [so] isn't a forum and questions still need to follow the SO guidelines for asking question while pointing them to `[ask]`. Also pointing out that this isn't TicketMasters Official support, they just don't seem to have one.

Comment: @Lankymart:  Let Tim's official message to them handle that on Monday.  There's no reason for you to intervene.

Comment: I claim 'They're there for you.' as the trademarked tag line for my support business (should I start one). Not only does it show someone else, somewhere else will deal with your issue (I'll likely point people here) but it also has a rather nice condescending pun built in as in 'There, there for you.' Like mocking someone who has an issue as if they are a small child you are trying to get to stop crying. Thanks Meta!

Comment: By war, did you mean downvoting their questions? Because I see a lot of negatives on question of that tag.

Comment: tristan, it might be helpful to link to the official help page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: @JDB That's a good link for someone working at TicketMaster to view.  If you think it should be part of this answer, please edit it in.

Comment: "I don't think this is anything we haven't seen or handled before".  Precisely because of this, I think a more high-level approach is in order.  If it happens increasingly, the approach of manually handling the result of companies doing this will eventually not be enough.  It would be good to come up with a way to try to affect some part of the cause.  See my comment on the OP for one suggestion.

Comment: @Laurel - For what it's worth, it looks like many of the ticketmaster questions are answered by self-identified ticketmaster employees, so at least they didn't just throw users into the back alley through the door labeled "Customer Assistance". There's actual staff members in the back alley.

Comment: @SahilKapoor I treat them just like any other tag, they are no different. I imagine the fact it's got a lot of exposure on here hasn't helped their cause. If it shows no lack of effort you can bet your life I'm voting it down, close voting as appropriate. I also left detailed comments explaining how questions could be improved. Out of a total of 12 questions 1 remains as that at least showed some research effort but still needs work.