# What to do about organisations that refer users to come to SO for support of their product?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

From the [Netty Project](http://netty.io/community.html)

> Getting involved with the Netty community is easier than you think.
>
> Post questions
> We use StackOverflow as the place to ask the questions. Just tag your question with 'netty', and then we will respond.

Which has resulted in the following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637991/netty-user-guide-refers-to-chapter-2-architectural-overview-does-it-exist#comment62774419_37637991

> [image: Question image]

<sub>I've posted a link and screenshots to the question and comments I'm referring to, as it will most likely be deleted in the future.</sub>

***1. We can comment and close such a question, but is there anything else we should do in this circumstance?***

***2. Is it better to post a question here or use the contact us form?***

***3. Do SE employees contact the organisation?***

***4. Should we support these open source projects that offer links to SO and the opportunity to place answers to the questions about their projects on SO?***

*The linked dupe asks SO to contact the organisation, I am asking what we are supposed to do when we see issues like this.*

Comment: SE employees contact the organization in these scenarios, I believe.  [Tim's going to have a busy day on Monday](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324489/ticketmaster-support-sending-customers-to-a-forum-here#comment353508_324489).

Comment: @Makoto [just what I said](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30975770#30975770)

Comment: why does it have the bar across saying it may already have an answer here with one close vote?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the proposed dup. The linked duplicate is about things that SO should do to prevent this happening, while this one is about what we should do when it _does_ happen. Same general topic, different questions.

Comment: I'm of the growing mind that SO should be disallowing such behavior in the first place. There have to be at least a dozen Meta threads scattered around, each revolving around a specific company which failed to properly keep its questions within SO's rules. In each case, the users are getting caught in the middle. I would argue we're not here to be ACME Corp.'s free support desk, and that if companies would like their questions outsourced they should be forming a contract with SO. Then SO gets paid, rules get followed, and everybody's happy.

Comment: @Makoto what are we supposed to do when we see it?

Comment: In my experience, it's been to get the attention of community managers via posts on Meta, but I'm not sure if that's the *best* way.

Comment: @Makoto well that's my question really, but it's been marked as a dupe :)