# Jelastic using Stack Overflow as product support

Tags: discussion, flags, scope, product-support

[Jelastic](https://jelastic.com/) seems to be using Stack Overflow as a tech support forum, using [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5479542/jelastic).

Their website points to Stack Overflow via "[Resources -> User Forum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jelastic)" link on their top level menu, and a sampling of questions they're involved in leave a bad taste in my mouth.  For example:

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929070/how-to-avoid-root-login-in-jelastic/49013468) looks like the question-asker had some previous support interaction with them, and the "3 answers" look like an attempt at a conversation thread. One of the answers refers to what seems to be internal details related to that customer that nobody else could have.
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653417/when-will-jelastic-support-alpn-for-nginx-http2-use/47694948) looks like a "when will jelastic support X" (there are [more than a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811456/jelastic-security-firewall-or-software-patches-for-the-ddos/34812523) of this style of question)
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160130/jelastic-docker-based-nodejs-environment-does-not-restart-correctly/50163539) has them "answering" with a request for more info -- "We need closer look logs of your apps."

I've found other meta questions ([this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325528/what-to-do-about-organisations-that-refer-users-to-come-to-so-for-support-of-the) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296893/more-actively-discourage-product-support-at-stack-overflow)) that talk about this in general terms, which seems to indicate just making meta-post to draw attention to it, so here I am.

**What (if anything) should be done about this user and the related questions? There's quite a backlog of "answers" already that seem to have flown under the radar so far.**

Comment: You could point them to https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support, I suppose. But really, just closing questions which should be closed, using the votes you have, etc. is the only sane path here. See [this answer on one of your linked questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296943).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - yeah, but there's also the general rule of "don't vote on the user, vote on the content" (going through a user's content and up/downvoting is pretty much guaranteed to get autoflagged as serial voting and reversed)

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to suggest you should vote on the user. Only those questions and answers which are in need of closure. You are correct about going through the user's content and down/up voting... Of course, there's nothing inherently wrong with going through the *tag's* content and voting for *closure* as needed. That's what's done during a tag burnination after all.

Comment: We'll get in touch with them. This can sometimes take a while, but we'll get in touch with them. Thanks for reporting it, we'll answer once we have.

Comment: @TimPost I am more concerned with the possibility of multiple users sharing a single account in the name of tech support. Can you, or another a moderator please look into this user's login history?

Comment: Well, that's brazen...

Comment: A tad related. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365918/ckeditor-telling-people-please-head-to-stackoverflow-for-support

Comment: You could also wonder if that shouldn't be on superuser.com

Comment: Can we ban the referrer? I'm mostly annoyed at the really bad questions.

Comment: @Krease: "don't vote on the user, vote on the content"  – There is nothing wrong with downvoting every single post of a user, **IFF** every single post of that user is crap. Downvoting crap is not "voting on the user", it is "voting on the content". If all of that content happens to be by the same user, then so be it. Serial voting is when you vote based on the *history* of content you have seen before. If you look at every post, and determine *individually*, without taking into account other posts you have seen before, that each one is crap, then you are not voting serially but individually.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - " If all of that content happens to be by the same user, then so be it." - [That's still serial voting, and gets reversed automatically.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: @Krease: According to my interpretation of the answer to that question, serial downvoting is a particular form of voting fraud. I can see nothing fraudulent in what you are doing. Serial downvoting is when you downvote posts purely because they are part of a series. But you are not doing that. You are downvoting them because they are *individually* worthy of downvoting, IOW you would also be downvoting them if they weren't part of the series, if they were by different users, for example.

Comment: It may very well be the case that the votes get reversed by some script, but that is a false positive in that script. Maybe even a bug. Not an indication of serial voting.

Comment: Are you proposing the closing of a question based on the participation of a given answerer?  That seems absurd to me. Are you proposing closing a questions if the asker comes from a particular domain?  Both seem like a bad idea/policy.  Let the question and answer stand for themselves.