# Etiquette of own corrigenda/improvements in answers

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I'm new to Stack Overflow, but I'm not new to programming forums in general, where it's relatively common to mark edits (by adding something like *"EDIT:"* prior to the new post material) in order to avoid disrupting the post flow.

Now, I realize that Stack Overflow answers have a publicly accessible edit history and should be self-contained and have no relationship with each other (and hence no history to preserve) rendering such practices less useful.

That said, sometimes I still feel an edit should be marked as such to emphasize the answer's chronological evolution.

Is this considered bad etiquette?

Comment: *"I'm not new to programming forums in general"* - but Stack Overflow is very much [*not* a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294774/is-stack-overflow-not-a-forum). Worry about someone seeing the question or answer a year from now, in its (presumably final) state.

Comment: I certainly use it when I have to change an answer because of a new library or framework version.  Typically to document a new feature that removes a previous limitation or awkwardness.  Not everybody jumps on the new stuff right away.

Comment: @HansPassant that is the main use case I had in mind; another situation I was thinking about is for giving credit to someone ...

Comment: @PaulRoub the SO/encyclopedia analogy is enlighting :)

Comment: The only time you should call out edits explicitly within the text of the post is when you are doing as Hans suggests and *changing* the nature of the post (*e.g.*, with a question after it has received answers, or with an answer to add information for a new version). Otherwise, it's just noise, as a detailed history is accessible with a single click. It's just like your source control's revision history feature replaced a bunch of one-off comments littering the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is considered bad etiquette.  You shouldn't include such notes in your edits, and you should be removing such notes from other posts when you're editing them.

If someone cares how the post came to be what it was, they can look at the revision history.  Whenever someone isn't looking at the revision history they only need to see the post as best as it can be presented.

Comment: ok, got it; as a side note, I assume it's still legit to *format* an answer to reflect pertinent chronological info, isn't it ? ( for example, an answer that turns out valid up to some date... )

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes It's certainly fine for an answer to describe what an answer might be for multiple versions of a product, or what an answer would be before/after some date where a relevant change happened.  There's no reason for such a post to indicate that the post hasn't been that way all along though.