# Why was this question about browser rendering deemed off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, close-reasons

I don't mind that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101885/how-repainting-a-single-render-layer-with-many-elements-works-in-browsers) was closed, as I already got an answer from a Chrome developer himself, who read it and replied to me via other means.

However, I would like to understand why this was deemed off-topic and eventually got closed.

The comments below the question make claims such as that it's a "why my code doesn't work type of question" and "there was no code example / no 3rd party sites allowed for code examples" and that "there is no clear question".

I refuted all these points, and I still believe that they do not hold up.

There is a code example, on a 3rd party site (the article linked in the comments does not make any mention of 3rd party sites being disallowed), the question is certainly not a "why doesn't my code work" type and there is a clear question worded.

I would really like some more specifics as to why it was deemed off topic, so that I can be more careful in the future.

---

I went ahead and updated the question as suggested in the comments here. Let me know if you still think it's regarded as off-topic, before I make a motion to reopen it.

Comment: The close message states "...code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**". Note the "in the question itself" part. Providing code on other sites is problematic because it could get deleted and render the question useless. The linked article doesn't state that, but help center about [What can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) does.

Comment: So, if I move the example code into the question itself it could be reopened?

Comment: I'm really not an expert in this area, but I imagine that a complete description of how modern browsers perform the layout process might take more text than suitable for the SO format (I guess one can write whole books about it). The algorithms used might also defer between browsers. I see more chances in getting an answer for your specific case, but for this you'll have to adjust your question.

Comment: Well, the Chrome developer solved my question in 2 tweets :) So while indeed one could write a pretty long and technical answer to this question (all the more appreciated), a shorter one could also do the job, as was the case

Comment: I think your question stands a better chance of not being closed if you edit it to be shorter and more to the point. You have a very concrete question, focus on that. Maybe start off with something along the lines of "I'm interested in why Chrome repaints only part of a layer in the following situation <snippet>".

Comment: Good to know: you editing your question has placed your question in the reopen queue automatically.

Comment: @Justastudent Thanks for pointing that out. Well, I figured it would be good to start the question the way it is now, in order to show people that *I have done my research* and I have at the very least a rudimentary knowledge of the subject. I always try to do that in most of my questions.

Comment: I'll take a stab at editing the question, then you can look at my edit and roll back any parts you don't like.

Comment: It is a very traditional mistake when asking questions.  Instead of showing the problem you are trying to solve, you ask users to write a manual so you can solve it yourself.  Nobody is going to write one in an SO post.  The close reason tells you explicitly what to do about it.  Don't ask for a manual, ask for a solution to your problem.  And provide the necessary info so that users can see your problem.

Comment: I've edited your question, focusing more on your actual question and less on the background you started off with before. I've also created a runnable snippet.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think that applies here though, I don't think I am asking users to write a manual for me with this question. I am not even asking for a solution. I am asking for someone to *explain* to me why I observe these results when *with my theoretical knowledge* I expected different results. All I ask is for someone who knows to fill in the gaps for me, so that the results make sense to me too.

Comment: Now that the question is reopened, you can answer the question, perhaps even quoting the two tweets by the Chrome developer...

Comment: Or even get Paul himself to answer here since he's active on the site...

Comment: @BoltClock I didn't want to bother him again, but sure, I'll contact him.

Comment: @Dimitris Karagiannis: Though if he'd rather not (because I see you've already self-answered), that's fine too.

Answer (score 47):

While I'm no moderator, I would have voted to close [your initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49101885/1). One of the problems we see over and over in the close queue is that people keep coming to SO and describing problems without including any code. [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294774/is-stack-overflow-not-a-forum), and the original question seemed to be inviting discussion, rather than answers.

Your revisions with a reproducible problem were more than enough to bring it back into line. As others have noted, you should now answer your own question with whatever the Chrome dev gave you, so others can benefit from this.

Comment: Fair enough. I still disagree with the point that there was no code in the original question though.

Comment: @DimitrisKaragiannis So, to understand that point better, let me explain why we want the code in the question: Answerers should not have to go off-site to be able to see your whole question and answer it. At the same time, if something happens to the link your code is behind, your question becomes useless for future users. So, it's really for your benefit that we ask that the code is in the question and not behind a link.

Comment: Fair enough, fair enough.

Comment: I added a close vote, but if I hadn't it would have been closed eventually. I can't add any more to this answer.